# How to clean data which has columns of 'Object' Data type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-cleaning

So recently again I was playing with NFL dataset and trying to do data cleaning assignment. While performing this activity, I came up with data which is of 'Object' datatype. Now the thing is I did some data exploration and what I came up with is that the columns has lot of unique values.
What I am looking for is to fill NaN values in this dataset and continue with this dataset.
I want to know some techniques which can be used to clean this type of data.

```
missing_columns1 = [var for var in nfl2.columns if nfl2[var].isnull().mean()>0]
for data1 in range(len(missing_columns1)):
    category1 = missing_columns1[data1]
    print(category1)
    print(nfl2[category1].dtype)
    print(nfl2[category1].isnull().sum())
    print(nfl2[category1].unique())
    print("---------------")
```

When I ran the above python code on the dataset, here the output that came.

`````
Tackler1
object
147183
['M.Griffin' 'C.Hope' 'S.Tulloch' ... 'T.Gurley' 'K.Peko' 'C.Kaepernick']
---------------
Tackler2
object
318045
[nan 'J.Farrior' 'S.Tulloch' ... 'D.Carrier' 'L.Trail' 'D.Lowry']
---------------
FieldGoalResult
object
354431
[nan 'No Good' 'Blocked' 'Good']
---------------
RecFumbTeam
object
358513
[nan 'PIT' 'TEN' 'MIN' 'DET' 'TB' 'NYJ' 'HOU' 'JAC' 'PHI' 'CAR' 'BAL' 'KC'
 'ATL' 'ARI' 'SEA' 'STL' 'NYG' 'WAS' 'BUF' 'NE' 'OAK' 'SD' 'NO' 'GB' 'CIN'
 'SF' 'CLE' 'DEN' 'CHI' 'MIA' 'IND' 'DAL' 'LA']
---------------
RecFumbPlayer
object
358513
[nan 'K.Fox' 'S.Tulloch' ... 'M.Paradis' 'A.Gotsis' 'F.Clark']
---------------
ChalReplayResult
object
359476
[nan 'Upheld' 'Reversed']
---------------
PenalizedTeam
object
336362
[nan 'PIT' 'TEN' 'CLE' 'MIN' 'NO' 'DET' 'TB' 'DAL' 'HOU' 'NYJ' 'JAC' 'IND'
 'CIN' 'DEN' 'PHI' 'CAR' 'BAL' 'KC' 'MIA' 'ATL' 'SF' 'ARI' 'STL' 'SEA'
 'WAS' 'NYG' 'GB' 'CHI' 'BUF' 'NE' 'SD' 'OAK' 'LA']
---------------
PenalizedPlayer
object
337483
[nan 'T.Polamalu' 'D.Stewart' ... 'D.Latham' 'D.Phillips' 'S.Rankins']
---------------
````
You can see that the columns has lot many unique values. 
How to fill Nan values based on this data in this column.
I have attached the dataset for your reference. You can find it in the release section since it is greater than 25 MB.
`````

Answer (score 2):

Null-like values can be replaced with `pd.DataFrame.fillna()` or `pd.Series.fillna()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
sample_data = {"FieldGoalResult": [pd.NA, 'No Good', 'Blocked', 'Good']}
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
df

  FieldGoalResult
0            <NA>
1         No Good
2         Blocked
3            Good


filled_df = df.fillna(value="filler_of_choice")
filled_df 

    FieldGoalResult
0  filler_of_choice
1           No Good
2           Blocked
3              Good
```